# Hyperledger Composer REST API for GET

Tags: hyperledger-composer

If for example  an Asset contains Relationships property for owner then when using GetSingle API (from a client App)  we get back something like:  "owner":"resource:somenamespace.owner#owner01". (i.e. related participant is owner with ownerId = owner01).

What is actually being returned for the relationship property?

Is there anyway we can actually get back all the properties of the related instance (owner with ownerId = owner01) in the same call? I have tried adding parameter to the Rest call such as below but no joy.?resolve=true&include=true.

If I can't get related instance properties in same Rest call then how do I extract out the related Id (e.g. owner01 in above example) from the returned "owner":"resource:somenamespace.owner#owner01"I can then do a separate GetSingle call to the owner Rest end point using the extracted ownerId?I have tried searching the web for docs on such Rest API parameters/processing of results but no joy.Many thanks.Lalji

Answer (score 1):

1) What's returned is a URI resource ID for the related object (ie owner)

2) Yes. Use Loopback filters to resolve. For example ('GET' call - eg. using httpClient or axios etc eg - two examples:

```
GET 'http://localhost:3000/api/CommodityAsset?filter={"where":{"assetId":"A01"},"include":"resolve"}'              // narrow filter - for one asset

GET 'http://localhost:3000/api/CommodityAsset?filter={"where":{"ownerId":"resource:org.acme.biznet.owner%23T01"},"include":"resolve"}'  // broader, assets owned by a particular owner, could be many
```

where %23 is '#' the encoded character used in Composer language relationship notation.